# Change Firefox homepage via bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, firefox

Hope all is well. Well I am trying to do this for quite sometime but still failing to achieve the result. I have written a bash script, aim is to change the homepage of Firefox over the network. After searching over the internet for hours, I came across this script,

```
sed -i 's|\('browser.startup.homepage',\) '\(.*\)'|\1 'http://www.somesite.com'|' .mozilla/firefox/*.default/prefs.js
```

I've edited this according to my needs and this is the script that I wrote,

```
#!/bin/bash
USR="root"
IP="81.149.1.246"
ID="123"
SCRIPT="sed -i 's|\('browser.startup.homepage',\) '\(.*\)'|\1 'http://www.mysite.com/index.html?id=$ID'|' .mozilla/firefox/*.default/prefs.js"
`sshpass -p 'pa55w0rd' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $USR@$IP "$SCRIPT" `
exit 0
```

The script runs, doesn't give any error, but when I go and check if any changes are made to the **prefs.js**, I don't see any. It's still set to the old URL.

Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated. Thanks for reading and spending some time on this. Looking forward to your replies.

Thanks

Comment: Write `~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/prefs.js` instead of `.mozilla/firefox/*.default/prefs.js`

Comment: OR try `set str=user_pref("browser.startup.homepage", "http://www.mysite.com/"); cd = "%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\" echo %str%>>prefs.js`

Comment: Thanks for the replies Jayesh, I'll give your suggestions a go, however, the firefox that needs changing is on a linux machine and I'm a newbie to Bash Scripting so not really sure if I can use your second suggestion. If I can, please do let me know how? Thanks

Comment: Jayesh ... tried your first suggestion and just like before, nothing really changed in the prefs.js file. Can you please check the script that I've written above, probably that might have any problem in it ... Thanks

Comment: Jayesh, Thanks for your help, the 2nd suggestion did work, all I had to do was write it in a linux sort of way and it worked :) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your prefs.js is not malformed and about:home appears only twice in your prefs.js:

```
cat prefs2.js | grep 'about:home' -ohn
   50:about:home
   59:about:home
```

you can replace the first instance of about:home to your link.

```
sed '0,/about:home/s//http:\/\/stackoverflow.com/' -i prefs2.js
cat prefs2.js | grep 'stackoverflow.com'
   user_pref("browser.startup.homepage", "http://stackoverflow.com");
```

and remember about char-escaping.

**//Edit**

If prefs.js doesn't contain about:home.

I created a new clean profile wit `firefox -ProfileManager` and there was no 'about:home' in prefs.js, so just added that line

```
echo 'user_pref("browser.startup.homepage", "http://stackoverflow.com");' >> prefs.js
```

and started firefox with that new profile. It worked, SO was my start page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply agilob, unfortunately my prefs.js doesn't even have a single instance of about:home, hence don't really know how I will be able to do this!! Any advice?!?

Comment: Thanks agilob, yes I exactly did the same thing and it worked :) ... I echo'd the text into prefs.js and it worked :) ... thanks for the great help :) ...